# Send message in private in Superuser

Tags: discussion, editing

OK, good day to you.

I'm actually trying to answer some questions, and i need answers to some of mine. Really, all my posts are actually edited. No problem about that, nothing bad. But in fact i want to learn how to make things better, so that could stop.

I saw someone - mister James K. Some of my posts was edited by him. I want to contact mister K, and ask him to point me to the rules about doing good posts, so the edition actually could be lowed down. So I'm checking mister K's profile, and i didn't saw any way to send him a damn message.

Could you be please be so glad to give me some info, about how to send private messages, how to right down good answers, matching the rules. No i don't want to send him porn pictures!

Have a nice day

Comment: there is a link at the bottom "Tour". If you go there the page explains how to use Super User. Click around a bit, and you'll get to the page about how to ask good questions: https://superuser.com/help/asking

Comment: Thanks a lot man !

Comment: "I" is always uppercase on English.

Answer (score 9):

There's no private messaging system - in fact, for most part SE's designed to minimise private interaction. The closest thing we have to a private messaging system for regular users is chat (And I don't ever recall seeing him there, and you can't really contact someone who hasn't used chat recently over chat).

So, there's no actual way you can contact another user privately.

Comment: More than enough thanks